# Scan a column to find value over a certain value, and move the entire column into a new dataframe in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning, outliers

```
x<-matrix(c(0.00009852, -0.00393314, -0.00049056, -0.00117636, 
-0.00283716,  0.00136866, -0.00536613, -0.00068090, 0.01528542, 
0.01221890, -0.00309366, 0.00379356,-0.00159904, -0.00259300, 
-0.00635427,  0.00446363,0.00119367,  0.00079657,  0.00419246,  
0.00090068,0.00160321,0.00623682, -0.00010090, -0.00070604),ncol=4)

x<-data.frame(x)
names(x)<-c("active","inactive","injured","rehab")


   active        inactive     injured      rehab
1 0.00009852   -0.00536613  -0.00159904  0.00419246
2 -0.00393314  -0.00068090  -0.00259300  0.00090068
3 -0.00049056  0.01528542   -0.00635427  0.00160321
4 -0.00117636  0.01221890    0.00446363  0.00623682
5 -0.00283716  -0.00309366   0.00119367 -0.00010090
6 0.00136866   0.00379356     0.00079657 -0.00070604
```

So I have this dataset called (x).
I want to

1) find the outlier of each of the column

2) scan the column if there's any value that lies over/below the outlier value

3) move the column that has outlier into a new dataframe called y.

Task 1, I use the following:

```
quantile1<-function(k){
quantile(k, 0.25)+IQR(k)
}

quantile3<-function(k){
quantile(k,0.75)+IQR(k)
}

lower_outlier<-apply(x, 2, quantile1)
upper_outlier<-apply(x, 2, quantile3)

View(t(lower_outlier))
   active       inactive    injured     rehab
-0.000048750  0.010112565 0.001094395  0.003545148

View(t(upper_outlier))
   active       inactive    injured     rehab
0.00232446    0.0227156    0.0045333   0.0069408
```

So now I have upper and lower outlier limit for each of the columns. How do I proceed with task 2 and 3? I believe one of the approaches is something like

```
x <- x[x <= value]
```

but Im not sure. Any advice is highly appreciated

Comment: Can you show the expected?  Try `i1 <- colSums(x > upper_outlier[col(x)] | x < lower_outlier[col(x)]) > 0]`  If it is to find columns that have any outliers, all of the columns in the dataset shows that behavior..  `y <- x[,i1, with = FALSE]`

Comment: @akrun I have no expected answer lol this is a dummy set for a much much larger set so I have no idea at all.....

Comment: @akrun yes the first line works, the second line doesn't. Maybe I misunderstood the question..... maybe I was supposed to remove the VALUES that are above the upper/lower outlier....

Comment: sorry, in that case `y <- x[, !i1, with = FALSE]`

Answer (score 0):

We can create a logical matrix with relational operators after making the lengths of the comparison objects same (by replicating), then get the `colSums` of the matrix, negate (`!`) so that columns having 0 outliers will be TRUE and others FALSE

```
i1 <- !colSums(x > upper_outlier[col(x)] | x < lower_outlier[col(x)])
```

Subset the dataset columns based on the index

```
y <- x[, i1, drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: Error in `[.data.frame`(x, , i1, with = FALSE) : 
  unused argument (with = FALSE)  for the second line

Comment: @MT32  Sorry, I forgot it is a data.frame and not a data.table.  It is `drop = FALSE`.  For the example, you will get 0 columns